# Length of a continental perimeter

Tags: regions, geography, geographics

Excluding the islands, how can the length of the perimeter of a continent be calculated?

To make the question more concrete, what is the length of perimeter of the African continent, excluding the island of Madagascar?

My initial attempt is as follows:

```
africaPolygon = Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]["Polygon"];
Perimeter[africaPolygon]
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

---

I am aware of the paradox pointed to by @Domen (Thanks). Let's say a ship travels close to the shore or an imaginary path on the land around the continental boundary, then how can the length of the perimeter be calculated?

Comment: You are aware that the coastline length is generally [not a well-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox) quantity, right? :)

Comment: This might be interesting for you [Measuring Fractal Dimensions of Coastlines](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2033588?p_p_auth=MsC681W7)

Comment: @Domen: From theoretical point of view of mathematician it might not have a well defined length but from practical point of view it surely has a well defined length (of required precision) because you can always chose your smallest unit that you will use to measure something.

Comment: I'd suggest GeoLength[GeoBoundary[Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]["Polygon"]]] .

Comment: Thanks @jose. I did try `Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]["BoundaryLength"]` but this information does not seem to be available.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, yes, that's the whole point of the problem: you have to _choose_ the minimal length, and the total length strongly depends on this choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The polygon for the African continent has 465 lists of geographic regions.

```
africaPolygon = Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]["Polygon"]
```

[image: polygon for Africa GeoGraphicRegion]

Usually, the first region is the largest, and we can select individual regions. For example, check the first region by drawing it with `GeoGraphics`.

```
geoRegion1 = Polygon[GeoPosition[africaPolygon[[1, 1, 1]]]];
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Red], geoRegion1}]
```

[image: geographic region]

Using [`GeoBoundary`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoBoundary.html) (introduced in version 12.2) the length of the region is:

```
GeoLength[GeoBoundary[geoRegion1]]
```

> ```
> 30 048. mi
> ```

Compare this value to the length of all 465 regions.

```
GeoLength[GeoBoundary[africaPolygon]]
```

> ```
> 43 417.6 mi
> ```

Let's repeat the method for Madagascar, and find the coastline is 4,532.34 mi.

```
geoRegion2 = Polygon[GeoPosition[africaPolygon[[1, 1, 2]]]];
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Red], geoRegion2}]
GeoLength[GeoBoundary[geoRegion2]]
```

[image: Madagascar]